# How to put labels on the negative side of the x-axis in chartJS?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I am creating a graph where I display how late or early x was. My labels show the intervals of time, for example, on time, 15-30 min late, 30-45 min late, I want to display late on the positive side of x-axis and early on the negative side of x-axis on the Barchart. How would I add labels to the negative side of x-axis?